# How to find out my own composer package stability?

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I have some own composer packages. I add them using composer directly from my github account (I have not created packagist.org packages for them yet).
I do understand that I can mark my package as stable using git tag like

```
$ git tag v1.0.1
```

The question is: Are there any specific rules or requirements for composer packages stability?
For example, do I have to add unit tests to my repository before marking it as "stable'. Or do I have to create "alpha" or "RC" tags first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything formal about how pre-release tags are applied. Most Composer projects use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), but that doesn't go into any detail of the pre-release stages. Overall their application is subjective and there aren't any formal requirements for any given stage.

The Wikipedia article on the [software release life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle) has a good description of the generally accepted use of the terms. You may also be interested in other views, such as [Jeff Atwood's](http://blog.codinghorror.com/alpha-beta-and-sometimes-gamma/) or [Drupal's](https://www.drupal.org/node/467020).

Ultimately, the stability of your software is something you are in the best position to judge. Unit tests and known bugs will help you to decide, but there isn't a checklist to run through (which perhaps wouldn't be a bad idea).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm already aware about semantic versioning, and you are right, it has nothing to do with the pre-release stages (thanks for an appropriate term by the way).
The links are helpful too. I have a starting point now, thanks.
I'll mark you answer as the Accepted one if there is no more appropriate one in a couple of days. (I'm not yet used to stackoverflow so I'm not sure when to mark answers as Accepted).

Comment: No problems, I'm also curious if there are other takes on the question. There are more details on marking on accepted on [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/188816).

Comment: Thanks for another useful link. I do know how to "accept" answers now. Marking your answer as accepted.